# why extra characters are appears in text file?

Tags: c, file, visual-c++

I have a file, such as the following (in hex).

```
1F 00 48 3A 18 00 00 00 53 00 70 00 6F 00 75 00 
73 00 65 00 5F 00 61 00 7A 00 61 00 6D 00 00 00
```

I am trying to read the binary data from the file and output it as text. My current code is as follows:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *pFile, *tempFile;
    pFile = fopen("C:\\wab files\\Admin.wab", "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
    {
        fputs("file error", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    tempFile = fopen("C:\\myfile.text","wb");
    if(tempFile == NULL)
    {
        fputs("file not open", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }
    int Contact_Id, Id_Size, Data_Info=0;
    fread(&Contact_Id, 1, 4, pFile);
    fread(&Id_Size, 1, 4, pFile);  
    Data_Info = Id_Size;
    char* Main_buffer = (char*)malloc(Data_Info*sizeof(Data_Info));
    fread(Main_buffer, 1, Id_Size, pFile);
    const wchar_t* src =   (unsigned short *) Main_buffer;
    wcstombs ((char*) Main_buffer,  src, Data_Info );
    fwrite(Main_buffer, 1, Data_Info, tempFile);
    free(Main_buffer);
    return 0;
 }
```

The output text file containts follow:

```
Spouse_azam _ a z a m
```

Why is `_ a z a m` shown in text file? I wants to write only `Spouse_azam`.

Comment: Please note, that `<iostream.h>` is deprecated and the line `const wchar_t* src =   (unsigned short *) Main_buffer;` can't compile because: conversion from `unsigned short *` to `const wchar_t *` isn't allowed implicit.

Comment: @Constantin: So what can i do to resolve this problem. Please write few line of code for me . Thanks you in advance

Comment: Well, you _are_ using the same dest and src for the wcstombs; what did you expect. Also, can you explain what you think, for instance, `malloc(Data_Info * sizeof(Data_Info))` does?

Comment: @ Mr Lister: I think for instance,                        malloc(Data_Info * sizeof(Data_Info))                                     to declare an array of size equal to size of variable Data_Info at run time .

Comment: So why multiply by sizeof(Data_Info)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is wrong:

```
char* Main_buffer = (char*)malloc(Data_Info*sizeof(Data_Info));
```

It should be

```
char* Main_buffer = (char*)malloc(Data_Info*sizeof(char));
```

Second, you are using the same buffer (`Main_buffer`) for both source and destination. The result is that the first part of the buffer is overwritten with the converted string, but the rest of the buffer is left untouched. You have 24 bytes initially in the buffer (if you allocate correctly), and the first 11 are overwritten, but the other 13 are left there.

There are two options: use a second buffer for the multi-byte string, or use the return value of `wcstombs` to know how many bytes the result string has:

```
int bytes = wcstombs ((char*) Main_buffer,  src, Data_Info );
fwrite(Main_buffer, 1, bytes, tempFile);
```

Comment: Using a second buffer is vastly preferred, given that the parameters to `wcstombs` are defined with the `restrict` keyword.

Comment: Also, the cast is superfluous, `Main_buffer` is already a `char*`.